# How to export SLA rules in HPE LoadRunner Analysis?

Tags: loadrunner

For every LoadRunner Analysis report, I am configuring SLA rules and applying it manually.

Is there any tweaks available to export the SLA rules, so that it can be applied quickly for the future test reports? Please share your approach, tips or tricks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured the SLA in the controller's design tab ?

Comment: Yes. I have done that.

Comment: And every time you launch results for this scenario in Analysis, it doesn't show the SLA settings ?

Comment: Is it possible to export, to reuse for my future Analysis?

Comment: No it's not... But I still don't understand your problem

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Can I post this as the answer ?

Comment: I am not sure. What if there are other ways to export the SLA rules.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I am posting this as an answer, feel free to accept it, unless you find a way to make it happen.

Comment: Okay. I will check and post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to export, to reuse for my future Analysis?**

No - LoadRunner (Current version 12.53 and below) **does not** support exporting SLA definitions for future scenarios.

Comment: Current version of LR is 12.53.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your .lrs file in notepad.  Look for entries related to your service level agreements.   Consider how you would apply them to future .lrs files which are created.

Or, you can move your SLA management into your test code as I do.  I replace the lr_end_transaction() with my own function which takes as parameters the current transaction name, an SLA value and the current status.  It then creates a secondary transaction for items which have a status of LR_PASS, but which run too long, villating the SLA.  I name these items _TooLong.   I pull the current elapsed time for the transaction using the lr_get_transaction_....() set of functions.

I can now compare quite easily those which are in SLA and those which are not in my standard report without having to set any SLA data inside of the scenario.   I also can have very fine level or control, on a per transaction, per location, per load generator basis as to the SLA value.